# How can I get language display name instead of ISO Language Code from browser using http user agent?

Tags: php, codeigniter, format

Is there any option for get language full name instead of ISO language code from browser using $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']?

I want to use this thing in one of my codeigniter project.

$data['language'] = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 5);

Output of **$data['language'] ==> en-GB**

**Right now my output is like this**

[Current Output of language code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BexPX.png)

And I want output like this

[I want this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag3u9.png)

Thanks in advance...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
Locale::getDisplayLanguage("nb-NO"); // Norwegian Bokmål
Locale::getDisplayLanguage("no"); // Norwegian
Locale::getDisplayLanguage("nb"); // Norwegian Bokmål
```

More info [on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php)